# Items don't show up when ng-repeat is populated in a timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, animate.css, wow.js

I'm using [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) to animate elements as the user scrolls to them on a page. I've loaded a bunch of elements into the browser using an `ng-repeat` and they animate just fine when loaded right away. You can see the elements loading properly in this demo:

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/eHsCF

However, when the data is added to the `$scope.items` array asynchronously, it doesn't appear to work.

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/KvpqB

You can see that the elements are added to the page if you remove the `.wow` class. The `.wow` class is hiding the elements but wowjs isn't revealing them as they show up on the page for some reason.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bad News

By trial and error I've found out that **[WOW's "asynchronous content support"](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW#asynchronous-content-support)** will only work if there is a `wow` element rendered in the DOM by the time you make the call `new WOW().init();`. Otherwise it won't synchronize anything.

## Prove:

### [Not Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pfYk7Jq6vfsh1F6bYh2?p=preview)

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rdWg0hDUE0vSYK1DfHDD?p=preview)

The only difference is that the working example has this dummy tag in it:

```
<section class="wow"></section>
```

### [Another Working Example based on your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kizfB)

So, if you want `WOW` to work asynchronously just make sure that you have a dummy element with the "wow" class on it before you make the `new WOW().init();` call.

## Previous Answer (also interesting, you may want to have a look at it)

Please, have a look at **[this example that I've made for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/73AYWJZflHqLx0J4WJl9?p=preview)**

```
angular.module('wowTest', [])
.factory('wowAPI', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {        
        getItems: function () { return $http.get('data.json'); }
    }
}])
.controller('wowController', function($scope, wowAPI, $timeout){
  $scope.items = [];
  wowAPI.getItems().success(function(data){
    $scope.items=data.items; 
  }).then(function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      new WOW().init();
    });
  });
});
```

Or **[the equivalent example with your original code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrxDy)**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $timeout(function () {
    for (var count = 0; count < 50; count++) {
      $scope.items.push({
        text: "Item " + count
      });
    }
  }).then(function(){ 
     $timeout(function(){
        new WOW().init();
      });
  });
});
```

The thing is that it seems that `WOW` actually needs to be instantiated after the DOM has rendered, so the function inside the `$timeout` ensures that code will be executed at the end of the `$diggest` cycle, after your browser has already rendered the new values of your `$scope` in the DOM.

I guess that you could also do this (see bellow), but I think that it's much better to chain the promises rather than have one inside the other:

```
.controller('wowController', function($scope, wowAPI, $timeout){
    $scope.items = [];
    wowAPI.getItems().success(function(data){
      $scope.items=data.items; 
      $timeout(function(){
        new WOW().init();
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why this works? Wowjs is supposed to handle elements added asynchronously yet for some reason it needs to be reinitialized here.

Comment: @AlexFord I don't know anything about Wowjs, but this example proves that Wowjs is not behaving how you say that it should. By making the call: `new WOW().init();` after the `$scope.$apply();` what I'm doing is to trigger the `$diggest` cycle that will make sure that the updated $scope will get rendered in your browswer and after that I'm initializing Wow... If that works and the previous code didn't means that Wowjs is not behaving how you thought that it would, sorry.

Comment: @AlexFord I've updated my answer, doing it this way it's safer and probably easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @AlexFord is there a reason why you haven't marked my answer as accepted? Do you think that my answer should be improved? Could you please let me know what you think it's missing? Thanks!

Comment: The reason is that because of the call to `$timeout` a digest is already in progress and the console reports an error in my app when I then also call `$apply`, yet for some reason in the pen example this isn't the case. I assure you it will be marked once I dive into this a little deeper.

Comment: @AlexFord wow!!! I didn't even realize that this was inside a `$timeout` function! I just did a kick answer! I completely overlooked at that. Let me have a closer look at it. No worries, you have a very good reason not to accept this answer.

Comment: It's interesting because if you remove the `$timeout` entirely then everything works fine, but if you use the `$timeout` then this bug occurs where none of the elements update. I don't understand why that is, or why calling `$apply` during an already executing digest cycle somehow fixes it. I'm guessing some kind of race condition is present between Angular and WowJS.

Comment: @AlexFord I was going to update my answer with that, I actually can explain you why. You mean this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/smpai, right?

Comment: WowJS is simple, it just adds functionality to detect when an element is in the user's viewport and animates it in. It's [supposed to detect elements added asynchronously](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW#asynchronous-content-support), which I know it's doing because if I remove WowJS then the elements load up fine within the timeout. If you inspect the DOM the elements are there, just hidden.

Comment: Right, without the timeout all is dandy. The timeout in the example is just a placeholder for the actual code in my app since it produces the same bug. The code in my app loads data via ngResource, which also ensures the callback happens within a digest cycle.

Comment: @AlexFord I just gave you a long answer/apology for my initial answer, if you don't want to accept my answer I completely understand it. Sorry for the confusion that my initial answer generated...

Comment: Haha, thanks for your help. No apology necessary. I know that I don't *need* to use a `$timeout` in my example. As I said earlier the `$timeout` is only present in my example in order to reproduce the bug. In my real app the bug is being produced by loading data via ngResource (also happens with a manual `$http` call or anything asynchronous that still maintains a digest cycle for the callback). I can't load the elements in my real app until the data comes from the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63738/discussion-between-josep-and-alex-ford).

Comment: @AlexFord I have updated my answer (again!). I'm pretty sure that this answer will finally solve the question. Thanks!

Comment: Nice catch! I'm going to file a bug with wowJS and reference your answer. Great work and thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's the bug report: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/133 ***Edit:*** And here's the fix! https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/pull/134